# Set Directory from result of RegistrySearch

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to add some files to a directory that I find with a RegistrySearch. I believe my RegistrySearch is correct:

```
<Property Id="IISROOT">
    <RegistrySearch Id="IIS_RegDir"
                    Type="directory"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="Software\Microsoft\InetStp"
                    Name="PathWWWRoot" />
</Property>
```

I want to use the IISROOT property as a reference to a directory where a file should be added.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="IISROOT">
    <Component Id="cmp_testBAT" Guid="">
      <File Id="fil_testBAT" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.myDir)\test.bat" />
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

I know this won't work, because I need a Directory if I want to use the DirectoryRef, but my problem is setting a Directory element to have the directory of the RegistrySearch result.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
   <Directory Id="IISROOT" Name/SourceName/FileSource="?"/>
   <!-- ... -->
</Directory>
```

From what I've read, I should only use Name if the directory doesn't already exist, and other source attributes have been deprecated, so (as far as I can tell), I need to use `SourceName` or `FileSource`. I've tried both, referencing `IISROOT`, both with and without square brackets, and changing the property and directory names to see if there is any difference in them being the same or different, but the result is always that the file is created in `C:`. I've also tried using `Name="."`, but this didn't change anything. The logs always just say that the `IISROOT` Directory element is set to `C:\`, but don't say if my property is set correctly (From checking RegEdit, I think it is correct, but I can't be 100% sure).

I have seen similar questions asked, but the responses are typically the implementation I currently have. What can I do to set my Directory element as the result of the `RegistrySearch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a default directory specified, usually under `ProgramFilesFolder` as a fallback in case the registry search doesn't return a value. For when the registry search works, it will normally override it. This way:

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyApp">
                <Directory Id="IISROOT" Name="IISFOLDER" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

Then you can use the IISROOT directory this way (even in a different file):

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents">
        <Component Id="Component_User" Guid="*" Directory="IISROOT">
            <File Name="My Test App.exe" />
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: This is creating a folder called IISFOLDER in the installation folder. Is this a sign that my RegistrySearch is not returning what I want it to?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I tested it using Name="PathWWWRootA" and it created the IISROOT. :)

Comment: One suggestion: You can add a condition to verify if the value is set. If not, raise an error and prevent your app from being installed.

Comment: Why would the RegistrySearch be failing? It's hard to know since the verbose logger doesn't mention Property assignments, but I can see that the Registry key and value are valid. I've also used this exact registry search before without any issues. In fact this project was originally working, but suddenly isn't. Could there be an external issue?

Comment: Sorry, but it is hard to say why the RegistrySearch is failing. One way to debug it is to output the result to a text control in a custom dialog.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion (it never occurred to me debug with a custom dialog). It's nice to be able to see my property values, even if the only way to do so feels incredibly circuitous.